# I have some problem about step Counter Google fit API

Tags: android, api, kotlin, google-fit

I am currently trying to work with Google Fit API. I have been mainly by following Google's documentation.

Below is the code that I have which seems to have a problem

The problem I have is that it shows me all step count. I want to return my app today step count.  this code return me **550530 steps.** I want to show today's step count.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), OnDataPointListener,
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {
    private var authInProgress = false
    private var mApiClient: GoogleApiClient? = null
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            authInProgress = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(AUTH_PENDING)
        }
        mApiClient = GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Fitness.SENSORS_API)
            .addScope(Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_ACTIVITY_READ_WRITE))
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build()

    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        mApiClient!!.connect()
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        Fitness.SensorsApi.remove(mApiClient, this)
            .setResultCallback { status ->
                if (status.isSuccess) {
                    mApiClient!!.disconnect()
                }
            }
    }

    private fun registerFitnessDataListener(dataSource: DataSource, dataType: DataType) {
        val request = SensorRequest.Builder()
            .setDataSource(dataSource)
            .setDataType(dataType)
            .setSamplingRate(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build()

        Fitness.SensorsApi.add(mApiClient, request, this).setResultCallback { status ->
            if (status.isSuccess) {
                Log.e("GoogleFit", "SensorApi successfully added")
            } else {
                Log.e(
                    "GoogleFit",
                    "adding status: " + status.statusMessage
                )
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onConnected(bundle: Bundle?) {
        val dataSourceRequest = DataSourcesRequest.Builder()
            .setDataTypes(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_CUMULATIVE)
            .setDataSourceTypes(DataSource.TYPE_RAW)
            .build()
        val dataSourcesResultCallback =
            ResultCallback<DataSourcesResult> { dataSourcesResult ->
                for (dataSource in dataSourcesResult.dataSources) {
                    if (DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_CUMULATIVE == dataSource.dataType) {
                        registerFitnessDataListener(
                            dataSource,
                            DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_CUMULATIVE
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        Fitness.SensorsApi.findDataSources(
            mApiClient,
            dataSourceRequest
        )
            .setResultCallback(dataSourcesResultCallback)
    }

    override fun onConnectionFailed(connectionResult: ConnectionResult) {
        if (!authInProgress) {
            try {
                authInProgress = true
                connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(
                    this,
                    REQUEST_OAUTH
                )
            } catch (e: IntentSender.SendIntentException) {
                Log.e("GoogleFit", "sendingIntentException " + e.message)
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("GoogleFit", "authInProgress")
        }
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        //++++++++
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_OAUTH) {
            authInProgress = false
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                if (!mApiClient!!.isConnecting && !mApiClient!!.isConnected) {
                    mApiClient!!.connect()
                }
            } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                Log.e("GoogleFit", "RESULT_CANCELED")
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("GoogleFit", "requestCode NOT request_oauth")
        }
    }

    override fun onConnectionSuspended(i: Int) {}

    override fun onDataPoint(dataPoint: DataPoint) {
        for (field in dataPoint.dataType.fields) {
            val value = dataPoint.getValue(field)

            runOnUiThread {
                Toast.makeText(
                    applicationContext,
                    "Field: " + field.name + " Value: " + value,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show()
            }
        }
    }

    companion object {
        private const val REQUEST_OAUTH = 1
        private const val AUTH_PENDING = "auth_state_pending"
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you try checking other values for             `setDataTypes(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_CUMULATIVE)`
As I think TYPE_STEP_COUNT_CUMULATIVE will give you all the steps

Comment: no, doesnot work

Answer (score 0):

The code is returning **550530 steps** because you are using `DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_CUMULATIVE`, CUMULATIVE will return the step count data as a sum since the start of the count or you can say from the beginning.

You can use `DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA` it will give you each data point not the sum of all.

You can check more in the documentation from [DataType](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/data/DataType)

Happy Coding!!